# Problem with accessing superclass methods in method redefinitions

Tags: ruby, methods, extending

I am having a bit trouble to understand when "super" can be called and when not. In the below example the super method leads to a no superclass error.

```
class Bacterium
  def eats
    puts "Nam"
  end
end

class Bacterium
  def eats
    super # -> no superclass error
    puts "Yam"
  end
end

b = Bacterium.new
b.eats
```

But this works:

```
class Fixnum
  def times
    super # -> works
    puts "done"
  end
end

5.times { |i| puts i.to_s }
```

Is 5 not just also an instance of Fixnum. And am I not redefining an existing method like in the Bacterium example above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not really. `Fixnum` inherits from `Integer` class, and you are in fact overriding `Integer#times`, so `super` works, as it calls implementation from the parent.

In order to achieve something similar when monkeypatching, you should alias method before redefining it, and there call it by alias.

```
class Bacterium
  alias_method :eats_original, :eats
  def eats
    eats_original # -> "Nam"
    puts "Yam"
  end
end
```

Class reopening is not a form of inheritance and `super` is of no use there.

Answer (score 3):

Just as Mladen said, and you can check that with `Class#superclass`:

```
irb> Fixnum.superclass
=> Integer
```

And does Integer implement `#times`?:

```
irb> Integer.instance_methods.grep /times/
=> [:times]
```

Yes it does.

So, in a simplified way, we can say, that super invokes the method you are in of a superclass. In your case the superclass of a `Bacterium` is Object, which doesn't implement `#eats`.

I said this is very simplified, because look at this example:

```
module One
  def hi
    " World" << super()
  end
end

module Two
  def hi
    "Hello" << super()
  end
end

class SayHi
  def hi
    "!!!"
  end
end

h = SayHi.new
h.extend(One)
h.extend(Two)

puts h.hi

#=> Hello World!!
```

Don't take to serious what I wrote here, it is actually tip of the iceberg of the Ruby object model, which is important to understand (I am still learning it) - then you will get most, or all of those concepts.

Use some Google-fu for "Ruby object model"...

Comment: Thanks for the nice example. Ruby is so powerful (but also cause of all its power sometimes a bit confusing).

Comment: I just want to add ... if module `One` is included into `SayHi` before the `hi` method is defined then `hi` of `One` is available as `super` in `SayHi`. So the order seems to be always important.

Comment: @Zardoz: IMHO, the best thing about Ruby is not that it's powerful (as many other modern languages are, really), but that it's achieved without adding specific syntax and keywords for every possible feature - the language is kept lean and clean. `alias_method` and `extend` are (just) ordinary methods, not language constructs or something.